# JaxB can not Serialize

Tags: java, ant, jaxb

I am using Ant, now I need to generate classes which should implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface. I am using a binding file to generate serializable classes, and I am using a dtd to define the classes. But, xjc throws the error  [xjc] [ERROR] cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jxb:bindings'. I am passing the binding file as an argument to xjc task :

```
        <arg value="-b"/>
        <arg file="../WebContent/DTD/bindings.xjb"/>
```

Here is my binding file

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    version="2.0">


    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

Kindly suggest the way out

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using a DTD. DTD comes from the prehistoric times and bindings file had a [different format](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/3461152ffe39baf32b8550d47d18d58cdbc139c5/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/resources/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/dtd/bindinfo/xjc.xsd) back then.

Try something like:

```
<xml-java-binding-schema xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
  <xjc:serializable/>
</xml-java-binding-schema>
```

Here's a [DTD example from the RI](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/3461152ffe39baf32b8550d47d18d58cdbc139c5/jaxb-ri/samples/src/main/samples/dtd/nameCard.jaxb).

Good luck.
And switch to XSD. :)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, I tried that, now the error is gone but still classes are not getting implemented the Serializable interface. :(

Comment: Try this whole example - does it work ? https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/tree/3461152ffe39baf32b8550d47d18d58cdbc139c5/jaxb-ri/samples/src/main/samples/dtd

Comment: If it does not work, another option is to use my inheritance plugin: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin
However I have never tried it with DTDs.

Comment: Forget the last comment, this won't work precisely because of the DTD. The plugin could however be extended to support command-line configuration, this would work then. Please file an issue here: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/issues if you want this.

Comment: Do I need to include the schema file as well or just updating the binding file will do the work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Include where? To do which work?

Comment: to make use of your inheritance plugin, so that all my class should implement Serializable interface

Comment: Ah, ok. No, just file an issue, I don't need your DTD, I'll just take any DTD, there's not difference.